How to give permission to .git for github-actions[bot]
I've created a repository on GitHub with a Blazor WebAssembly project. I aim to deploy the website to a separate branch to view it via GitHub Pages.
I created a a GitHub action:
# This is ".github/workflows/gh-pages.yml" file.

name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - root
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      # Checkout the code
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      # Install .NET Core SDK
      - name: Setup .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: 8.0.x

      # Publish the site
      - name: Publish
        run: dotnet publish MyBlazorApp/MyBlazorApp.sln -c:Release -o:publish -p:GHPages=true

      # Deploy the site
      - name: Deploy
        uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v4.0.0
        with:
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          publish_dir: publish/wwwroot
          force_orphan: true

based on this NuGet Package.
My problem is:
/usr/bin/git push origin --force gh-pages
remote: Permission to ReusableTemplates/BlazorWASMwGithubPages.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/ReusableTemplates/BlazorWASMwGithubPages.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Action failed with "The process '/usr/bin/git' failed with exit code 128"

The repo can be found here: https://github.com/ReusableTemplates/BlazorWASMwGithubPages

Apologies for answering my own question, but thanks to Stack Overflow's functionalities I learned that the problem lies in:
Settings -> Action -> General -> Workflow permissions and choose read and write permissions
If you can't change it and you have your repository in an organization do it in the organization's settings.
Answer found here.
